# What is the 'subharmonic' account on macOS Catalina (10.15.3)?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, user-account

My MacBook Pro running Catalina (10.15.3) has been behaving a bit weird lately. So, I wanted to list the users that exist:

```
$ dscl . -list /Users PrimaryGroupID | grep ' 20$'
clint                    20
subharmonic              20
```

I'm user 'clint'. But who is user 'subharmonic'? I didn't create that user and I've searched the web but found no references. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It may be a long shot, but you should definitely download and run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac-download/) to check to see if your MBP has any malware on it. Is 'subharmonic' a standard or an Admin account?